# Sending XMLHttpRequest via Javascript under iNotes client

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I want to post data using **XMLHttpRequest** in a form and provide the same functionality under various environments. The following well-known code creates the request for me.

```
function createRequest() {
      var result = null;

      if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            // MSIE
            result = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          } 
      else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // FireFox, Safari, etc.
        result = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (typeof xmlhttp.overrideMimeType != 'undefined') {
          result.overrideMimeType('text/xml'); // Or anything else
        }
      }
      else {
          alert("What a bad browser!")
        // No known mechanism -- consider aborting the application
      }
      return result;
    }
```

This works fine in the system web-browser and in the default web/browser of iNotes client. But when run in a normal form in iNotes client, no suitable object is found to send the request.

My question is whether iNotes client provides **some alternative for sending such requests**.

A negative answer would also be appreciated since it would help me make decisions!

Comment: The name 'iNotes client' generally refers to accessing Lotus Notes mail through a web browser. Is that what you are asking about??

Comment: No. I meant the native iNote client. Not through a web-browser.

Comment: Okay, I think you must mean the native Lotus Notes client. There is no such thing as a native iNote client. Can you explain why you want to do this in Javascript in the Lotus Notes client?  I'm not sure if that's possible or not, but I do know that it is possible to do it from Lotusscript.

Comment: IBM got rid of the "Lotus" in their products. The official name of v. 9 is simply Notes!

Comment: I am actually already implementing my Application as Java agents. The goal from JavaScript would have been to provide the same functionality for both clients, Notes and the web Clients.